# Неверно отрабатывает scroll event на Safari десктоп

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, safari, gsap, touch-event

Необходимо отслеживать скролл на странице и при пересечении блока на 60 пикселей вверх/вниз проскроливать к следующему / предыдущему экрану (Элемент занимает 100svh).
Для проскроливания к элементу использую GSAP
На хроме, файрфоксе и прочих работает как задуманно.
На Сафари (проверяли на десктопе) не срабатывает проскроливание к элементу и отражается только первый и последний элемент

```
export const animateTechMobile = () => {
  const TABLET_WIDTH = 752;
  const isTablet = window.matchMedia(`(max-width:${TABLET_WIDTH - 1}px)`).matches;

  let panelsSection = document.querySelector(".fragment");
  if (!panelsSection) return;

  var body = document.body;
  var docEl = document.documentElement;
  let currentElt;
  let currentPoints;
  const wrapperElt = document.querySelector('.fragment__wrapper');
  const listElt = panelsSection.querySelector('.fragment__list');
  const beforeElt = panelsSection.querySelector('.fragment__before');
  const topElt  = panelsSection.querySelector('.fragment__top');
  const allPanels = panelsSection.querySelectorAll('[data-element]');
  const points = panelsSection.querySelectorAll('[data-point]');
  const h1Elt = panelsSection.querySelector('.h1');

  let headerHeight = document.querySelector('header').getBoundingClientRect().height;

  let heightForFix = isTablet 
    ? headerHeight + 20 + listElt.getBoundingClientRect().height
    : 300;

  let isFixed = false;
  let isClicked = false;
  let currentId = 0;
  let animated = true;
  let delta = 0;
  let startY = null;
  let timer = null;

  allPanels.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.paddingTop = `${heightForFix + 50}px`;
    item.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;
    item.style.transform = `translate3d(-40%, 0, 0)`;
    if (isTablet) {
      const textElt = item.querySelector('.fragment__elt-content');
      const imgEltHeight = item.querySelector('.fragment__img').offsetHeight;
      textElt.style.height = `${window.innerHeight - 110 - imgEltHeight - heightForFix}px`;
      textElt.style.paddingBottom = '60px';
    }  
  });

  const removeClasses = () => {
    if (!Boolean(currentElt)) return;

    if (currentId > 0 && currentId <= allPanels.length && Boolean(currentElt)) {
      currentElt.classList.remove('active');
      currentPoints.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('hovered'));
      currentElt.style.transform = `translate3d(-40%, 0, 0)`;
    }
  };

  const setActiveElts = (index) => {
    currentElt = panelsSection.querySelector(`[data-element="${index}"]`);
    currentPoints = panelsSection.querySelectorAll(`[data-point="${index}"]`);
  };

  const setClasses = () => {
    currentElt.classList.add('active');
    currentPoints.forEach(item => item.classList.add('hovered'));
    currentElt.style.transform = `translate3d(0, 0, 0)`
  };

  const scrollIntoViewHandler = (item) => {
    gsap.to(window, {duration: 0.5, scrollTo: item, autoKill:false});
    isClicked = false;
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      animated = true;
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }, 500);
  };

  var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";

  if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, function(e){scroller(e)});
  } else if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, function(e){scroller(e)},false);
    function scroller(evt) {
      //Guess the delta.
      delta = 0;
      if (!evt) evt = window.event;
      if (evt.wheelDelta) {
        delta = evt.wheelDelta/120;
      } else if (evt.detail) {
        delta = -evt.detail/3;
      }
      // if (evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
      // evt.returnValue = false;

      //Do the magic.
      //callback(delta);
    }
  }

  const fixElts = () => {
    isFixed = true;
    topElt.setAttribute('style', `padding: 0;`);
    if (!isTablet) {
      h1Elt.setAttribute('style', `font-size:20px;`);
      beforeElt.setAttribute('style', `position: fixed; top: 59px; height: ${59 + heightForFix / 3 * 2}px;`);
      document.querySelector('.technology-slide__img').style.width = 'fit-content';
      document.querySelector('.fragment__block').style.height = `${heightForFix - headerHeight}px`;
      document.querySelector('.technology-slide__img img').style.height = `${heightForFix}px`;
    }
    if (isTablet) {
      topElt.setAttribute('style', `max-height: 50%;`);
      beforeElt.setAttribute('style', `position: fixed; top: 59px; height: ${59 + listElt.getBoundingClientRect().height}px;`);
    }
    
    panelsSection.style.paddingTop = `${wrapperElt.getBoundingClientRect().height}px`; 
    wrapperElt.classList.add('fixed');
    wrapperElt.style.paddingTop = `${80}px`;
    topElt.style.height =  `${heightForFix}px`;
    wrapperElt.querySelector('.container').style.height =  `${heightForFix}px`;
    wrapperElt.style.height =  `${heightForFix}px`;
    wrapperElt.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionendHandler);
  };

  const unfixElts = async () => {
    if (isTablet) {
      beforeElt.setAttribute('style', ``);
      topElt.style.height =  `calc(${window.innerHeight}px)`;
      topElt.setAttribute('style', ``);
    }

    if (!isTablet) {
      h1Elt.setAttribute('style', ``);
      topElt.setAttribute('style', ``);
      beforeElt.setAttribute('style', ``);
      topElt.style.height =  `calc(${window.innerHeight - headerHeight}px)`;
      document.querySelector('.technology-slide__img img').style.height = '100%';
      document.querySelector('.technology-slide__img').style.width = 'auto';
      document.querySelector('.fragment__block ').style.height = 'auto';
    }
    
    wrapperElt.style.paddingTop = `50px`;
    panelsSection.style.paddingTop = 0;
    wrapperElt.style.height = `${window.innerHeight}px`;
    wrapperElt.classList.remove('fixed');
    isFixed = false;
  };

  const moveElt = () => {
    removeClasses();
    setActiveElts(currentId);
    scrollIntoViewHandler(currentElt);
    isClicked = false;
    setClasses();
  };

  const moveToNext = () => {
    if (animated) {
      if (currentId < allPanels.length) {
        currentId = currentId + 1;
        moveElt()
      }
    }
  };

  const moveToPrev = () => {
    if (animated) {
      if (currentId === 0) {
        gsap.to(window, {duration: 0.5, scrollTo: document.querySelector('.top-scroll')});
          // document.querySelector('.top-scroll').scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
      }
        if (currentId > 1) {
          currentId = currentId - 1;
          if (currentId >= 1) {
            moveElt();
          }
        }
    }
  };

  const transitionendHandler = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (!isClicked) {
      currentId = 1;
      moveElt();
    }
    wrapperElt.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionendHandler)
  };

  const scrollHandler = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // evt.stopPropagation();

    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
    

    if (scrollTop > headerHeight) {
      if (!isFixed) {
        fixElts();
      }
    } else {
      unfixElts()
      removeClasses();
    }
    if (delta === -1) {
      
      if (currentElt && currentElt.getBoundingClientRect().top < -60) {
        console.log(delta, currentElt.getBoundingClientRect().top , currentElt.getBoundingClientRect().bottom);
        moveToNext();
      }
    }

    if (delta === 1) {
      console.log(delta, currentElt.getBoundingClientRect().top, currentElt.getBoundingClientRect().bottom, window.innerHeight);
      if (currentElt && currentElt.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 60 > window.innerHeight) {
        moveToPrev();
      }
    }
  };

  document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', (evt) => {
    startY= (evt.touches || evt.originalEvent.touches)[0].clientY;
  }, true);

  document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', (evt) => {
      if (!startY) return;
      // if (animated) return;

      evt.preventDefault();
      const xDelta = startY - (evt.touches || evt.originalEvent.touches)[0].clientY;
       if (xDelta > 40) {
          moveToNext();
          startY= null;
      } else if (xDelta < -40) {
        moveToPrev();
        startY= null;
      }
  }, false);

    const pointScrollHandler = (evt) => {
      evt.preventDefault();
      isClicked = true;
      animated = false;
      const target = evt.target.closest('[data-point]');
      currentId = parseInt(target.dataset.point);
      console.log(currentId)
      moveElt();
    };


  let callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting && currentElt) {
          wrapperElt.classList.add('absolute');
          beforeElt.style.position = 'absolute';
        } else {
          wrapperElt.classList.remove('absolute');
          if (isFixed) {
            beforeElt.style.position = 'fixed';
          }
        }
    });
  };

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {threshold: 0.4});
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('footer'));

  const panelVisibilityHandler = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          if (Boolean(currentElt)) return;          
          if (entry.target.classList.contains('active')) return;
          currentId = parseInt(entry.target.dataset.element);
          moveElt();
        } 
    });
  };

  let newObserver = new IntersectionObserver(panelVisibilityHandler, {threshold: 0.2});
  allPanels.forEach(item => newObserver.observe(item));
  

  points.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', pointScrollHandler));
  document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler, {passive: false});
}
```

Comment: По-хорошему для этого IntersectionObserver используют в современном мире.